# Associative array lookups (from code in Three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, associative-array

I'm looking at the code in three.js, specifically the THREE.SphereGeometry method to create a sphere:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/SphereGeometry.js

There are 2 sets of loops - I'm looking at the second one.

My question is this:
There's an array of arrays that's created, called vertices.  Into this array are added arrays of objects.

Later, a single object is retrieved using indices, specifically:

```
var v1 = vertices[ y ][ x + 1 ];
```

Then, just below this, it appears the object is again referenced but by this syntax:

```
var n1 = this.vertices[ v1 ].clone().normalize();
```

Try as I may, this seems like a bug to me .. wouldn't `this.vertices[v1]` return undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what makes this confusing is `this.vertices` vs `vertices`.  They are in fact two different structures.

```
// first loop
for (...) {
    /* ... */

    // this.verticies will have every vertex
    this.vertices.push( vertex );

    verticesRow.push( this.vertices.length - 1 );
    /* ... */
}

// notice we pushed a row of vertices to `vertices` not `this.verticies`
vertices.push( verticesRow );


// second loop
for (...)  for (...) {
    // grab the vertex from the local list
    var v1 = vertices[ y ][ x + 1 ];

    // use it to grab something from the object's list
    var n1 = this.vertices[ v1 ].clone().normalize();
}
```

Comment: Ah!  Doh!  I should have caught that.  Thanks!

Comment: A great example of why you should avoid reusing variable names -- it confuses others who will have to work with your code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that specific example, but here is a contrived data structure that would be valid, and not necessarily an error.

```
x = 1
y = 2

vertices = ["","",["","x",3],"the third element"]

var v1 = vertices[y][x+1] // v1 is `3`

var n1 = this.vertices[v1]

alert(n1)
// alerts `the third element`
```

Comment: True, but the OP says "Later, a single object is retrieved using indices, specifically" ... "var v1 = vertices[ ......."  (not an int)

Comment: Same principle: `vertices = [{},{},{2:3},{a:"b"}]` ... `alert(n1.a)` alerts `b`. The point is that an inner object can contain an index to another object in the outer array.

Comment: That makes no sense - the OP says an object is being retrieved...you can't pass an object to `[]` to index an array. You're right that an object's property can contain an index, but when the OP says "an object is retrieved", then it doesn't matter...

Comment: You are right. I am assuming that an object is not retrieved, and actually an integer, representing an array key is retrieved.